# localscroll: How to fire event after scroll

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using localscroll and it has an option to fire a function before the scroll takes place by using the onBefore parameter but there doesn't seem to be one for after the animation. Does anyone know how you can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the onAfter as well, it is provided by the scrollTo plugin. The settings object is passed to that plugin so all its settings can be used as well, note that the arguments received are different.